# Are you having a lecture now?

Tags: sentence-construction

Is it  okay  to ask:

> Are you are having a lecture now?'

Or:

> Are you at lecture now?

would that be more correct?

Answer (score 2):

Chances are, you don't want either.

We wouldn't normally ask "Are you having a lecture now?".  To a native speaker, it wouldn't sound right unless you were asking whether an organisation had reached a decision on whether to hold a lecture, and even then, "are you *holding* a lecture" would be preferred.  This is unlikely to be what you mean. "Are you at lecture now?" is not correct either because it is missing an *article*.  Here are some correct and idiomatic ways to ask the question, with notes on the differences between them:

- "Are you at the lecture now?": I have a particular lecture in mind which I am expecting you to attend, and I want to know if you are there yet.
- "Are you at the lecture?": I have a particular lecture in mind, but I don't know whether you are attending.
- "Are you at a lecture now?": I don't know what your timetable is, and I want to know if you're at a lecture (as opposed to, for example, being available for something else).
- "Are you at a lecture?": Same again: I know it's possible you're at a lecture, but I don't know what lectures you might be at.

You need the "a" or "the", because "lecture" is singular and not a proper noun.  This is complicated somewhat, because there *are* some events that we treat like proper nouns (notable examples include being "in class" or "at prayer"), but a lecture is not among them.

Comment: Maybe the missing article was an oversight, or maybe it was general confusion about English grammar, but it might be worth pointing out the difference between, "Are you at a lecture" and "Are you in class."  I wonder if the original poster assumed that because being at a lecture is like being in class, you could omit the article.

Comment: It's true, the missing article may have been an oversight.  In the end, it doesn't matter: if mentioning it doesn't help the asker, it still might be important for a future reader.  "Are you at a lecture" versus "are you in class" is a good point to raise, but I'm not sure how to phrase it.  I'll see what I can cook up.

Answer (score 0):

To supplement Darael's good answer...

We don't normally say that we're **having** a lecture.

But there is a particular usage, at least in American English, where the verb **lecture** is transitive and means "to berate, to harangue", where we can using **having**.

> Okay, okay. I wish you would stop lecturing me about it!

And so Tommy could tell his friend Billy that he cannot come outside and play:

> I can't come out and play, Billy. I'm having a lecture.

or

> I can't come out and play, Billy. I'm getting lectured.